# Which layout to use?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, border-layout

I want to make with swing this interface:

[image]

And when I resise it I want all the subpanels and buttons to be resized like this: [image]

Not only main window  to be resized. I am using GridBagLayout. And I dont know how to stick the borders of the panel with GridBagLayout to the borders of the Frame in that way, when I am resizing the frame the panel also to be resized.

Comment: What about showing your code?

Answer (score 9):

I normally use nested layouts for this.

- Use a `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout` as the base.
- Store your central components in a `JPanel`, and add this to the `CENTER` of the `BorderLayout`.
- Store your bottom components in two separate `JPanel`s.
- Create another `JPanel` with a GridLayout of 1 row and 2 columns.
- Add the two `JPanel`s to it in the correct order.
- Add this `JPanel` to the `SOUTH` of the `BorderLayout`.

Answer (score 3):

The property to achieve this, i.e. when JFrame is resized the JPanel should also resize itself, will be `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`. It appears to me that your **Left JButton** is a bit smaller than the **Right JButton**. If you really wanted to achieve this with **GridBagLayout**, here I have crafted a small sample code for your help, have a look and ask any question that may arise :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GridBagExample
{
    private JPanel contentPane;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBag Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setOpaque(true);
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        gbc.weighty = 0.9;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;  // appears to me this is what you wanted

        contentPane.add(centerPanel, gbc);

        JButton leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        JButton rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.3;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;

        contentPane.add(leftButton, gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.weightx = 0.7;
        gbc.weighty = 0.1;

        contentPane.add(rightButton, gbc);

        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new GridBagExample().displayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: GRIDBAGEXAMPLE OUTPUT :]